# popuating country and state dropdown in cq form element dropdown(not dialog)

Tags: forms, drop-down-menu, aem

I am using cq form and have a dropdowns dragged and dropped on the form for country and states.

How do i make states available on change of country.(I am populating country options from a item load path i.e. a node has all countries as its children).

I searched a lot all I am getting is how to do it in dialog box.but thats not what I am looking for.

I want to populate the /libs/foundation/components/form/dropdown component.

Any help is welcome.

I am using cq 5.6.1 (aem 6 adaptive forms has some way to do it)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it

- Add the FORM component to the page
- Add **Dropdown List** component in between the above Form Start/End
- Right-click on the dropdown component, select Edit. In the dialog, enter the Element Name(Country), Title, and in "Items Load Path" enter the node path from where data need to be filled in.
- Add another **Dropdown List** component
- Right-click on the dropdown component, select Edit. In the dialog, enter the Element Name (State), Title, and in "Items Load Path" enter the node path from where data need to be filled in. Save to come back to dialog.
- In the dialog, choose **Show/Hide**, a dialog popups up. Choose **Country** "is equal to" some value "say US". This value should match the values in the above Country dropdown. Save and exit.

That's it.

[image: Country Dropdown List]

[image: State Dropdown List]